# What Jordan curve of length $1$ maximizes the expected length of a chord between two uniformly picked points on it?

Tags: probability, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, plane-geometry

For a (sufficiently nice) Jordan curve $\sigma :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with unit length and natural (w.r.t. arc length) parametrization, we denote the expected value of the distance between two points that are picked from the path independently and uniformly by $c(\sigma)$. So

$$c(\sigma) = \mathbb{E}[ \space|\sigma(T_1)- \sigma(T_2)| \space],$$

where $T_1, T_2 \sim U([0,1])$ are independent.

> What path maximizes $c$?

For example, for $\sigma =$ circle (of radius $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ to have unit perimeter),
$$c(\sigma) = \frac{2}{\pi^2}$$

([It is known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleLinePicking.html) that for unit circle we get $\frac{4}{\pi}$ so scaling leads to the value $\frac{2}{\pi^2}$.)
Is circle the maximizing path?

PS. Here is [a small application](https://codepen.io/ploosu2/full/dzegbO/) for testing different kinds of paths. The circle seemed to be the best among all paths I tried out.

Comment: With your definition of $c$, one can achieve more than $2/\pi^2$. Namely, let $AB =1/2$ and $\sigma(x) \approx A$ on $[0,1/2)$, $\sigma(x) \approx B$ on $[1/2,1)$. Then $c(\sigma) \approx 1/4$. You probably want $\sigma$ to be the natural parametrization?

Comment: Yes, natural, arc length, parametrization is what I'm after. I'll edit it in somehow...

Comment: I believe that "Jordan" is a red herring; I suspect it'll turn out that among ALL closed curves --- let's say twice differentiable or something -- it'll turn out that the circle is optimal, hence it's also optimal among Jordan curves.

Comment: A stronger conjecture: for any $a\in (0,1/2)$, the expected distance of a chord with arc length $a$,  $\mathbb{E} [|\sigma(\{t+a\}) - \sigma(t) |] $, is maximized by a circle (here,  $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part).

Comment: That appears to be solved (your question, not my stronger conjecture); see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02760067?LI=true)

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty certain that a straight line segment is the optimizing path.

For then the expected length appears to be $\frac{1}{3}$ (if my back-of-the-envelope computation is correct), which is much larger than $\frac{2}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: It should be a Jordan path (starting point = ending point).

Comment: Ah...I assumed that "Jordan path" meant "Jordan arc"; I believe a more common term is "Jordan curve".  A google-search count bears this out.

Comment: Yes 'curve' sounds better. I edited the question.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a **tentative partial** answer to the revised question (where "arc" has been replaced by "curve"). Let's call the curve $u$, with $\|u'\| = 1$, i.e., it's parameterized by arclength.

**I'm going to make one leap here,** which is to replace the expectation of *distance* with the expectation of *squared distance*. This is similar to replacing "length" with "energy" when finding geodesics on a manifold, but without my copy of Morse Theory here at home, I cannot reproduce the argument...so **much of what follows may well be incorrect**.

Now the optimal curve can be translated so that its center of mass is at the origin, i.e., so that 
$$
\int_0^1 u(t) ~ dt = 0.
$$

The thing we're optimizing is
\begin{align}
E(u) 
&= \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 |u(t) - u(s)\|^2 ~ds ~dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 (u(t) - u(s)) \cdot (u(t) - u(s)) ~ds ~dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  - 2u(t) \cdot u(s)) + u(s) \cdot  u(s) ~ds ~dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1   u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~ds ~dt -  \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 2u(t) \cdot u(s)) ~ds ~dt + \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 u(s) \cdot  u(s) ~ds ~dt \\
&= \int_0^1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~dt -  \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 2u(t) \cdot u(s)) ~ds ~dt + \int_0 ^ 1 u(s) \cdot  u(s) ~ds 
\end{align}
The first and last terms here are the same, so they can be combined:
\begin{align}
E(u) 
&= \int_0^1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~dt -  \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 2u(t) \cdot u(s)) ~ds ~dt + \int_0 ^ 1 u(s) \cdot  u(s) ~ds \\
&= 2\int_0^1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~dt -  \int_0^1 \int_0 ^ 1 2u(t) \cdot u(s)) ~ds ~dt  \\
&= 2\int_0^1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~dt -  2\int_0^1 u(t) \cdot\int_0 ^ 1  u(s)) ~ds ~dt  \\
&= 2\int_0^1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~dt -  2\int_0^1 u(t) \cdot0 ~dt  \\
&= 2\int_0^1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~dt.
\end{align}

So now the problem is reduced to this:

Among all unit-length loops whose average is the origin, which one maximizes
$$
E(u) = \int_0^1 u(t)\cdot u(t)  ~dt?
$$

I *suspect* that's a standard Calc. of Variations problem with the circle being a well-known answer, but I can't promise that.

Anyhow, there you have at least a start at an attempt on the problem.